# mu4e how to change lookup directory fro mu4e-action-view-as-pdf function

Tags: emacs, elisp, mu

I'm trying to get to work the view as pdf function in mu4e, and I guess that the problem is the lookup directory of the executable `msg2pdf`.
From the function definition I see

```
(defvar mu4e-msg2pdf "/usr/bin/msg2pdf" "Path to the msg2pdf toy.")

(defun mu4e-action-view-as-pdf (msg)
  "Convert the message to pdf, then show it.
Works for the message view."
  (unless (file-executable-p mu4e-msg2pdf)
    (mu4e-error "msg2pdf not found; please set `mu4e-msg2pdf'"))
  (let* ((pdf
      (shell-command-to-string
        (concat mu4e-msg2pdf " "
          (shell-quote-argument (mu4e-message-field msg :path))
          " 2> /dev/null")))
     (pdf (and pdf (> (length pdf) 5)
        (substring pdf 0 -1)))) ;; chop \n
    (unless (and pdf (file-exists-p pdf))
      (mu4e-warn "Failed to create PDF file"))
    (find-file pdf)))
```

where I changed the `(defvar mu4e-msg2pdf "/usr/bin/msg2pdf" "Path to the msg2pdf toy.")`
 to match the path where `msg2pdf` is.
The problem is that from the debugger I see

```
Debugger entered--returning value: nil
  file-executable-p("/build/buildd/maildir-utils-0.9.9.5/toys/msg2pdf/msg2pdf")
* #[(msg) "\305!\204\n ......
* mu4e-action-view-as-pdf((.....
  mu4e-view-action()
  call-interactively(mu4e-view-action nil nil)
```

that the lookup path is not what I specified. Since I tried to chage it in different ways and apparently `mu4e` is ignoring me, does anybody knows how can I set the correct lookup path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the the variable `mu4e-msg2pf` to the path of the executable `msg2pdf` by adding the following to your init file

```
(setq mu4e-msg2pdf "/path/to/msg2pdf")
```